# Solving differential equation using scipy.integrate.odeint: "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats."

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions

I am working on drawing a graph of this non-linear first-order differential equation:

```
dv/dt + 3 v**2 + 2 = 0
```

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def diff(v, t):

      return [v, -3*v*v - 2]

t = np.arange(-1,1,0.01)

v0 = 1

f = odeint(diff, v0, t)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.plot(t, f)

plt.show()
```

However, this does not work:

> odepack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`odeint` routine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) expects the first parameter to calculate the derivative only:

> **func** : *callable(y, t0, …)*
>   Computes the derivative of y at t0.

However, your function `diff` returns a 2-element list *containing the solution in addition to the derivative*:

```
def diff(v, t):

      return [v, -3*v*v - 2]
```

To fix this you simply need to remove `v` from the return value and avoid wrapping it in a list:

```
def diff(v, t):

      return -3*v*v - 2
```